# Track redirection links

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink

Is it possible to track which links redirected to my site? For example if it's a short URL http://alturl.com/6rp7w that redirects to http://www.mysite.com would I be able to track http://alturl.com/6rp7w?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether or not that is the URL passed as the referrer. If you have a public site you can test with, set up a small url and point it to a test php page and put this:

```
<?php
  echo getenv("HTTP_REFERER"); 
?>
```

If the URL is the same, then the referring URL is passing the small URL and you can track it. If the referrer shows up as `http://alturl.com`... then chances are you will not be able to track the actual URL.

Comment: Yes that echos the page with the link but not something like `http://alturl.com/ta6s9` I guess there's no way to do it?

Comment: Correct. You can only get what the referring server is sending. So if they are not sending anything else, then you cannot retrieve that information when it sends a referrer. The upside is, typically these URL shortening things will use the same URL. So if you know the page they are hitting, you can do a reverse lookup so know which link it came in from (but that is out of scope for this question).

Comment: reverse lookout. Thanks! I do some research on that!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable is going to be the closest thing you'll get.

Comment: Thanks but I need to find out the link instead of the site the link was posted on